# Make HTTP server un-listen port 80

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I have an http server listening on port 80:

```
require('http').createServer(app).listen(80);
```

How can I programmatically make it unlisten port 80 after, say, 10 seconds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have a server stop listening use [`server.close`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/http.html#http_server_close_callback).

Answer (score 1):

If you want the server running, change the port:

```
setTimeout(function() {
app.set('port', 1337);
}, 10000);
```

Something like that?